# Spring Boot Scheduler throws InterruptedException

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler, interrupted-exception

I have a SpringBoot Scheduler which is executed every 1 sec. The scheduler throws **InterruptedException** . Now ,this scheduler often stops working and then gets restarted automatically after few minutes. The InterruptedException is not handled anywhere in the code. So ,can this be the reason of the scheduler stopping? If yes , how can this exception be handled?
Below is the code snippet-

````
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${OUTBOUND_MESSAGE_CHK_SCHEDULE_FREQUENCY}")
    
public void fetchOutBoundMessages() throws InterruptedException{
        
log.debug("fetchOutBoundMessages started>>");
        
if(LockHolder.hasValidLock()){
            
log.debug("Fetching Outbound message for >>>>>>>>>");
            
JSONArray jsonArrayObj= service.putOutBoundService(boroCode);
        }
        
else {
            
log.info("Lock has not available..");
        }
    }```
````

Comment: It's not clear where `InterruptedException` comes from (which method).

Comment: fetchOutBoundMessages() is the scheduling method which throws InterruptedException according to the code

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve, as you're saying running the method at every second, and it's throwing an exception in a few minutes. (Probably the scheduled method is running in multiple threads at the same time). For handling the exception you can look at this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception

Answer (score 0):

`InterruptedException` is an exception that gets thrown by Java synchronization primitives when the thread they are waiting in gets interrupted from another thread via the [`Thread.interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) method. The `Thread.interrupt` method is the Java way for gracefully cancelling concurrent tasks.

In your case it means that the method `fetchOutBoundMessages` was waiting on a lock of some sort and there was a thread in your system that for some reason decided to call `interrupt` on the thread running `fetchOutBoundMessages`.

Maybe try to set a breakpoint on `Thread.interrupt` to see who does that and why.